# Permission Denied with PHPMailer / SMTP / LimeSurvey

Tags: openssl, smtp, phpmailer, smtp-auth, limesurvey

Do you know how I may troubleshoot PHPMailer or LimeSurvey so I may send email with SMTP and TLS?

I'm using LimeSurvey 3.17 with PHPMailer 6.0.7 to send email with SMTP but its is not working or showing a meaningful error message.

So I created a test php file for PHPMailer and got these errors:

> Connection: opening to smtp.example.com:587, timeout=300,
>   options=array() Connection failed.
> Error #2:
>   stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to smtp.example.com:587
>   (Permission denied) [...phpmailer/src/SMTP.php line 321]
>  SMTP
>   ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Permission denied (13) 
> SMTP
>   connect() failed.

Test file

```
<?php
require '../src/PHPMailer.php';
require '../src/SMTP.php';
require '../src/Exception.php';

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

$msg = '';
if (array_key_exists('email', $_POST)) {
    date_default_timezone_set('Etc/UTC');
    $mail = new PHPMailer;
    $mail->isSMTP();
     $mail->Host = 'smtp.example.com';
    $mail->Port = 587;
    $mail->setFrom('user@example.com', 'Server Test');
    $mail->addAddress('user@example.com', 'John Doe');
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 4;
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                                  
    $mail->Username = 'user@example.com';   
    $mail->Password = 'j83kc74,%8#ge'; 
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';   
    $mail->Port = 587;  
    if ($mail->addReplyTo($_POST['email'], $_POST['name'])) {
        $mail->Subject = 'PHPMailer contact form';
        $mail->isHTML(false);
        $mail->Body = <<<EOT
        Email: {$_POST['email']}
        Name: {$_POST['name']}
        Message: {$_POST['message']}
        EOT;
        if (!$mail->send()) {
             echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
            $msg = 'Sorry, something went wrong. Please try again later.';
        } else {
            $msg = 'Message sent! Thanks for contacting us.';
        }
    } else {
        $msg = 'Invalid email address, message ignored.';
    }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Contact form</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Contact us</h1>
<?php if (!empty($msg)) {
    echo "<h2>$msg</h2>";
} ?>
<form method="POST">
    <label for="name">Name: <input type="text" name="name" id="name"></label><br>
    <label for="email">Email address: <input type="email" name="email" id="email"></label><br>
    <label for="message">Message: <textarea name="message" id="message" rows="8" cols="20"></textarea></label><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I was able to send an email with the commands below. Therefore, I have access.

```
echo -n "\0user@example.com\0j83kc74,%8#ge" | base64
RETURNS: XDB1c2VyQGV4YW1wbGUuY29tXDBqODNrYzc0LCU4I2dl

openssl s_client -starttls smtp -crlf -connect smtp.example.com:587
EHLO there
AUTH PLAIN XDB1c2VyQGV4YW1wbGUuY29tXDBqODNrYzc0LCU4I2dl
MAIL FROM:user@example.com
RCPT TO:another_user@example.com
DATA
This is a Test. Hello World.
.
QUIT
```

UPDATE 1:

> php -i | grep -i socket
>  /etc/php.d/20-sockets.ini, Registered
>   Stream Socket Transports => tcp, udp, unix, udg, ssl, sslv3, tls,
>   tlsv1.0, tlsv1.1, tlsv1.2
>  mysqli.default_socket =>
>   /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock => /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
>   pdo_mysql.default_socket => /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock =>
>   /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
>  sockets
>  Sockets Support =>
>   enabled
>  default_socket_timeout => 60 => 60

UPDATE 2: 
I was able to send an email with Grafana (Dashboard software) but I don't think it uses php and openssl.   So I guess it has something to do with http or php.   I wonder if I have an apache setting that needs to be changed.

I also tried this command:

> setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect 1

UPDATE 3:
Selinux is disabled and I set the value below in PHPMailer and I was able to send an email with a test php file.  Limesurvey is not working but at least I know that the mail will send.

> public $do_debug = DEBUG_LOWLEVEL;

Comment: Looks like a PHP config problem - perhaps the socket functions have been disabled? Can you check your php.ini settings? (run `php -i` on your command line)

Comment: Thanks.  I added an update.

Comment: I think this is likely an SELinux problem - take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19684371/333340).

Comment: Thanks. No luck. I added an update.

Comment: Are you sure it's not some other SELinux (or maybe AppArmor) setting? What binary needs the policy applied to may not be quite as in that answer, for example you may need to apply it to PHP-FPM rather than apache (httpd). Try turning SELinux off altogether; if it works you'll know it's in there somewhere. Also anything that contravenes SELinux rules should be logged, so check there too.

Comment: Selinux is disabled and I have the same issue with limesurvey.  The server is blocking my test php file.  I also looked in the logs for httpd, mail, and secure.  The mail log had an error for postfix but I think that is related to maldet that's in my crontab.  I have not installed postfix.  This is on Centos 7 / Azure.  I was also not able to send email with Wordpress plugins.

Comment: I added an update.

Comment: I've rolled back your last edit. It is not appropriate here to add SOLVED to the title or edit an answer into the question. If you've solved the problem and would like to share that solution, do so by writing an answer in the space below that is provided for that purpose. See [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) for more information.

Comment: Synchro's response provided the solution.